# What is the maximum number of augments that you can install on an agent?

Tags: invisible-inc

In the game Invisible Inc, what is the maximum number of augments that you can install on a single agent?

I'm doing a mission with agent Sharp at a cyberlab. By default, Sharp already comes with 6 augment slots, instead of the usual 2 that agents normally start with. Is it possible to create a 7th socket on the agent at the cyberlab?

[image]

Comment: Created the tag for you.

Answer (score 9):

The majority of agents start with a single unique augment pre-installed, with another single socket open and ready for another augment to be fitted at any time. They also have an additional two sockets that need to be unlocked by a Cyberlab's Augment Grafter.

This means that **the majority of agents have a limit of 4 augment sockets**.

Note that archive versions of Banks and Shalem 11 start with no augments pre-installed and two open sockets. Their limit remains the same.

You can see this in the screenshot below, showing Decker using an Augment Grafter.

[image: Cropped screenshot of Invisible Inc show agent Decker's available augment slots at a Cyberlab Augment Grafter]

As you have identified, however, **Sharp is the exception, with a higher limit of 6**. He starts with all his available sockets unlocked, one taken up by his unique augment and the other 5 unlocked and ready for fitting.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of augment sockets that an agent can have is 6.

If you try to install a 7th socket at a cyberlab, you'll get a message saying that the agent has reached his or her augment slot capacity.

Comment: Partially correct: AFAIK only Sharp can reach 6, the rest has a maximum of 4.

Answer (score 1):

The question was "what is the maximum number of augments that you can install on a single agent?" not "what is the maximum number of augments that a single agent can have installed?" so, the *technically correct*<sup>†</sup> answer is,

At most, you may install as many as augments as 5 (on Sharp) plus the number of augments you've *drilled out*.

If you drill out an existing augment and replace it with another, that's another augment that you've installed, even if the agent no longer has it. *8')

<sup>† Which, as we know, is the best kind of correct.</sup>